# Automating work in system

Tags: python

Looking to automate a tedious daily task. The process involves writing off breaks that are under a certain level. The coding should be simple the issue is I am working in a system that is provided by a 3rd party. Could anyone point me in the right direction to automate this task?

Comment: This is really, really vague. Also, it's not the kind of question SO was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script that completes the task and use a [crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to run this script daily.